# Cancelled Sessions from Student s letting confirmation lapse finding their way into the queue

Tags: django

I'm using django. I'm having an with a website were tutors can connect with students. There is a bug were  students who have cancelled there session are still finding there cancelled session back to the queue, I'm seeing the unfulfilled requests has jumped from 34 on Monday to 75 now and I'm wondering how many of those requests are real. I cant find the source code

I Cant find the source code and I need to locate it first